# Condition not being hit

Tags: angularjs

Why isn't the condition being hit when `'1'` is typed into the text box?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBZDwC1qkh8S13vH0gSe?p=preview

Comment: Because that code is executed once, when controller is created. Never after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), like:

```
  $scope.$watch('category', function(newValue){

    $scope.content = newValue === '1' ? 'Content for 1' : 'Content for everything else';

  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/iLhCHUTxO91dCi3SOprL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just in the constructor of your controller. It fires when the controller is created and then never executes again. You'd need to add that code to a method of the controller and then call that method from an event in the HTML.